# using the turtle module without opening the canvas (to obtain coordinates)

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

Is it possible to use the turtle module to obtain coordinates (turtle.pos() once at the desired locations) without it opening a canvas?

I know this probably seems silly and defeats the point of the turtle module, but it's actually a very useful way of getting the coordinates of some points I need.

Many thanks

Comment: I think `turtle` is too intimately connected with `tkinter` to be capable of running without `tkinter` being initialized - which necessarily creates a window.  You can hide that window by calling `.withdraw()` on it, or you can use `t = turtle.RawTurtle(tkinter.Canvas())` to create a turtle that is not connected with the window at all.

Comment: Might be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Can you provide more context of your original problem X? There might be a better solution than turtle.

Comment: I'm obtaining coordinates by: moving along circle segments (using the turtle circle method) then moving to an offset perpendicular to the turtle (turning the turtle 90 degrees). I have a series of circle segments for which the chord length and versine is known, and I am converting these to a radius and degree to use with the turtle circle method. I'm sure there is a better way! However, the turtle module works fine, I just don't need to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running turtle *standalone*, you could run it *embedded* and withdraw the root window on startup:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle

root = tk.Tk()

root.withdraw()

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=500, height=500)

turtle = RawTurtle(canvas)

turtle.sety(-1)

turtle.circle(1, extent=45)

print(turtle.position())
```